# Some ActiveAdmin pages not found after deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activeadmin

After deploying my app to Heroku, everything is working fine, except for some ActiveAdmin pages.

I get the following error:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

for these pages:

```
/admin/login
admin/users/1
```

while the root page works fine

```
/admin
```

Comment: Is you app being hosted in a sub-uri? If so `/admin` is a different location to `admin`. That is, `/admin` is relative to site root and not your app's root, whereas `admin` is relative to your app's root.

Comment: Kindly elaborate your comment?

Answer (score 0):

*This is an extension of a comment - and may not be the answer to the problem.*

In production environments, web apps can be hosted within a sub-uri. This allows you to host many apps at one location. Simplistically, instead of:

`app1` being hosted at `app1.example.com` and `app2` at `app2.example.com`

With sub-uris you would have the two apps at the same host:

`app1` at `example.com/app1`, and `app2` at `example.com/app2`

This works well, but means you have to be very careful with additional functionally that is added by mounting an engine the way `ActiveAdmin` does.

The main issue is the location of `/`.

For `app1.example.com`, root (`/`) is the same for the host and the app. And therefore `/admin` and `admin` both point to the same location `app1.example.com/admin`

For `example.com/app1`, app root is different to host root. Host root is `example.com` and app root is `example.com/app1`. If in your app you link to `\admin` in this environment, `admin` will be relative to your host and not your app. The result of this is that links to `/admin` go to: `example.com/admin` rather than `example.com/app1/admin`.

Therefore you have to be very careful to use `admin` as the root of all `ActiveAdmin` links in a sub-uri environment, and not use `/admin`.

There are some versions of `ActiveAdmin` where the use `/admin` appears for some links, and this causes some problems in a sub-uri environments. You also need to be careful with any links that you may have added.